# an example of a robotic arm in ROS

Tags: ros, manipulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have to do a small project in which I must simulate a robotic arm. I found ROS software very interesting and I would like to use it in order to complete my project. However, I spent a lot of time reading all kind of sites about how to get it started with no results. Does anyone know an application that could fit for my case and how it must be installed?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10297/an-example-of-a-robotic-arm-in-ros/) by [sergiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/707/sergiu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [URDF tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials) guide you step by step in creating the model of your robot arm, and running it in the [Gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo) simulator.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi sergiu,

Have you looked at OpenRAVE (http://openrave.programmingvision.com)? It's one of the best manipulation software platforms out there. There is a openrave ROS package and its standalone version is available from Ubuntu's package manager and works under Windows as well.

You can easily set up your own robot arm in OpenRAVE and use its existing planning tools to plan motions for it.

Huan

---

Originally posted by [liuhuanjim013](https://answers.ros.org/users/446/liuhuanjim013/) with karma: 152 on 2011-06-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Once you have a urdf and controllers running in Gazebo, you can use the arm_navigation wizard to configure our motion planning algorithms for your arm.  And even without controllers you should be able to plan and visualize those plans.  Check out http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation for general information and install instructions, and this tutorial in particular: http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Automatically%20Generating%20Arm%20Navigation%20Configurations/Planning%20Description%20Configuration%20Wizard

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-09-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2